# How to define a route in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm trying to define a route in `routes.rb` and I can't do anything from [this Ruby on Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) that will let this error pass.

```
No route matches {:controller=>"devise/home"}
```

Here's my routes.rb source.

```
SchoolCMS::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => "home#index"

  devise_for :teachers, :admin

  resources :home, :only => :index
  resources :admin, :only => :index

  resources :events do
    resources :event
  end

  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end  

end
```

Comment: What code is generating that error?

Comment: <%= link_to 'Home', :controller => 'home' %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be safe I would remove `devise_for :teachers, :admin` and split it so that it is

```
devise_for :teachers
devise_for :admin
```

I'm not sure you can specify multiple devises the way you use it, see if this fixes your error.

Also try to use path helpers were possible so instead of doing `<%= link_to 'Home', :controller => 'home' %>` make it `<%= link_to 'Home',  homes_path %>` but make sure you define your home as `resource :home, :only => :show` since it's a singular resource.

Comment: It's undocumented, but [the source code](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb#L136) seems to indicate that one can. Even so, I'd try making this change to see if anything happens :)

Comment: Btw, what fixed the error for you? Was it the splitting up of the devise_for or the changing the link ? I am having a similar error...so trying to troubleshoot.